# Importing Data Very Slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

Each month I need to import between 1-1.5 million rows of archived data. I first import it into a temp table (Tasks$) then run a stored procedure to insert into permanent table as needed. Importing into the temp table takes only a few seconds. The stored procedure however, takes 2-3 hours to run. Is there a better way than how I'm doing this or is this just the nature of what I'm trying to do and no way around the long run time?

If I run this without the merging of the rows (no STUFF/SELECT commands) it runs very quickly, so I am aware thats where the delays all are.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_DataArchive
(
    EmployeeID int,
    StartTime Time(0),
    Task nvarchar(25),
    Duration int,
    Details nvarchar(max),
    Weekdays nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp_DataArchive
SELECT EmployeeID, StartTime, Task, Duration,
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + A.Tasks FROM Tasks$ A
        WHERE (A.EmployeeID=B.EmployeeID) AND 
            (A.StartTime=B.StartTime) AND
            (A.Task=B.Task) AND
            (A.Duration=B.Duration)
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As Details,
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + A.Weekdays FROM Tasks$ A
        WHERE (A.EmployeeID=B.EmployeeID) AND 
            (A.StartTime=B.StartTime) AND
            (A.Task=B.Task) AND
            (A.Duration=B.Duration)
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As Weekdays
FROM Tasks$ B
GROUP BY EmployeeID, StartTime, Task, Duration
```

For the sake of completeness I should add that after that is done, I additionally need to convert the Weekdays into separate bit type columns which I do with the following but this only takes a few seconds to run.

```
INSERT INTO DataArchive
SELECT EmployeeID, StartTime, Task, Duration, Details,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Monday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS M,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Tuesday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Tu,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Wednesday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS W,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Thursday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Th,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Friday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS F,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Saturday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Sa,
    CASE WHEN Weekdays like '%Sunday%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Su
FROM #Temp_DataArchive

drop table #Temp_DataArchive
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION** - 
I was missing indexes on my original temp table (Tasks$). Added those indexes and the insert into *#Temp_DataArchive* is down from 2-3 hours to 2-3 minutes.

Comment: hard to say exactly what the problem is, but have you looked at the execution plan?  Just check to ensure you ruled out missing or non-optimal index.

Comment: any clustered indexes on DataArchive?

Comment: Greg beat me too it - but if you decide an index is needed, you may find you need to drop it before populating the temp table, and then re-add it before selecting out of it.

Comment: @Greg - The delays happen with the first query which is inserting into a temp table named `#Temp_DataArchive`. I'm actually creating that table just before the query is run, I'll modify my original post to show that.

Comment: No, not necessary to show the create table, what i'm saying is, continue to isolate the problem statement.  Remove the INSERT part, and run the SELECT only.  Is it still slow?  if so, look at execution plan.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help but parse this question to, "I'm breaking First Normal Form, and now my performance sucks.  When I don't break First Normal Form, performance is great.  Why?"

Comment: @Greg yes thats what I meant to say in my original post is that the SELECT only portion is whats slow, not the INSERT part. I did look at the execution plan and just shows each of the two table scans at 21% and each of the execute scalar as 28%. I'm seeing nothing missing so maybe the long processing is just to be expected with how I'm merging the rows?

Comment: @Greg - I'd give you points if I could. I was missing Indexes on the original temp table (Tasks$) and was too busy looking at #Temp_DataArchive. I added indexes and now only taking about 2 minutes to run my proc.

Comment: Execution plans are the cheapest form of performance investigations, glad you saw the table scans and resolved them.  Now, all you need to do is evaluate whether or not 2 min is expected.   Two things come to mind - tempdb could be bottlenecking, or XML processing.  Work with your DBA to see if tempdb is optimized, and continue to evaluate your XML parsing, there is a good suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

It is the XML processing with so much data that is slowing you down.

I don't understand why you would want to take your data already nicely parsed into rows and put them into comma separated lists.  You gain no benefit and making things harder to query in the future.  Just import the rows as is.  If you need them combined for a view in an interface, just have the client build the comma list for the particular items they are querying.  If you are trying to save space, you could create an identity ID field for each (EmployeeID, StartTime, Task, Duration) and then create a relationship table to your tasks (ID, Task).

Comment: I actually have a very specific need for merging the data as I'm doing. Its not just a traditional data archive but data compiled from multiple departments and reporting done based on specific criteria. If I don't import it in the way needed, then when someone pulls a report for these purposes, they would first need to do this then do the calculations which would be done several times per day while pulling reports. Its more cost effective in this case to do as I'm doing than to leave it as separate rows as the separate data is never used on this server like that.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't until I was posting the result that I realized you had already found a solution (doi!). I won't jibber-jabber about indexes like I was going to but also give this format a shot. It's usually faster for me and it's my go-to list combiner style.

**Please also read the comment about using STUFF/FOR XML.**

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Task, xtask.*, xdetail.*
FROM dbo.Task b
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT [TaskList] = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT
      N', ' + a.Task
    FROM dbo.Task a
    WHERE a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE
    -- Pull out the value from the xml or xml-escaped chars will stay escaped (ie. <>&)
    -- If you don't need to worry about that, you can remove this part to save a little time
  ).value(N'.', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
) xtask
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT [DetailList] = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT
      N', ' + a.Details
    FROM dbo.Task a
    WHERE a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
    FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE
  ).value(N'.', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
) xdetail
GROUP BY EmployeeID, Task
```